# Conditional formatting of exported filtered items in JIRA

Tags: jira

I recently customized the structure of filter exports to Excel following the instructions found at https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Customising+JIRA+Excel+Output. This is great if you want to change the look and feel of the exported excel file.

However, how would I achieve conditional formatting based on status of exported issue set. For example, I would always like to see the "Closed" issues in Green color and "Ready to Test" items in Yellow. How do I achieve this?

Expected outcome
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the Traffic Light add-on to create a custom field with the chosen color. 
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/de.polscheit.jira.plugins.traffic-light_status
This is less distracting than coloring an entire row I find.

Comment: But since the template file mentioned in the link (searchrequest-excel-header.vm) is a Velocity markup you could also do clever things with Velocity code (http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html)

Comment: I dont necessarily want the colors in JIRA screen. I just need the coloring when I export it to excel. Its easier for the non techy business stakeholders to distinguish whats going on as most managers just want to know what is being tested and whats already is signed off.

Comment: @modar - I will take a look at the velocity code. This looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Better Excel Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.midori.jira.plugin.betterexcel) to export JIRA issues to custom Excel spreadsheets.

Important difference: these are real Excel files (XLSX format), unlike the HTML tables produced by the built-in Excel export feature.

You can use so-called tags to implement custom behaviour in the template. These are similar to HTML or JSP tags. In your case you should use the [jt:style](http://jett.sourceforge.net/tags/style.html) tag to specify the *fill-background-color* and *fill-pattern* properties, and wrap it in a [jt:if](http://jett.sourceforge.net/tags/if.html) condition.

*Disclaimer: I'm a developer working on this plugin.*